# Duplicate code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, duplicates

Is the following a good example of how to remove duplicate code in JS to explain to a class?
Can someone give me a better one that maybe touches other angles as well as ways to improve this one?

```
let employees = [{
    name: 'Paul',
    type: 'Manager'
  },
  {
    name: 'Rich',
    type: 'Developer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Rob',
    type: 'Cleaner'
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    type: 'Developer'
  }]

var findManager = function(){
  employees.forEach(function(person){
    if (person.type == 'Manager') {
      console.log(person.name);
    }
  })
}
var findCleaner = function(){
  employees.forEach(function(person){
    if (person.type == 'Cleaner') {
      console.log(person.name);
    }
  })
}
var findDeveloper = function(){
  employees.forEach(function(person){
    if (person.type == 'Developer') {
      console.log(person.name);
    }
  })
}
```

//CODE REFACTORED BELOW

```
var findParticularEmployment = function(employment){
  employees.forEach(function(person){
    if (person.type == employment){
      console.log(person.name);
    }
  })
}

var findDeveloper = function(){
  return findParticularEmployment('Developer')
}

var findManager = function(){
  return findParticularEmployment('Manager')
}

var findCleaner = function(){
  return findParticularEmployment('Cleaner')
}

findManager()
findCleaner()
findDeveloper()
```

Comment: This is probably better asked @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For this particular use case the suggested refactoring is fine.

Comment: Sure. Although the functionality to run after the employee has been found should probably be refactored out as well; I'd just return the person.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var findEmployee = function(employeeType) {
  employees.forEach(function(person){
    if (person.type == employeeType) {
      console.log(person.name);
    }
  })
}

findEmployee('Developer');
findEmployee('Cleaner');
findEmployee('Manager');
```

Comment: but more susceptible to typos/case problems, a enumeration findEmployee(Employee.Developer) would mitigate that.

Comment: how would that look @AlexK.?

Comment: `var Employee = { Developer: "Developer", Cleaner: "Cleaner" };`

Comment: @AlexK. thanks. is that not duplication in itself though?

Comment: and also when I just ran them both in the console. Employee.Developerssssss and 'Developersssssss' they both gave the same result...(i.e.  the object one didn't give me more notice on an error)

Comment: Employee.Developerist inside the function would be undefined, you would check for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one object with `{type: [names]}` and then you can get names array by using type as key.

```js
let employees = [{
  name: 'Paul',
  type: 'Manager'
}, {
  name: 'Rich',
  type: 'Developer'
}, {
  name: 'Rob',
  type: 'Cleaner'
}, {
  name: 'Chris',
  type: 'Developer'
}]

var obj = employees.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e.type] = (r[e.type] || []).concat(e.name)
  return r
}, {});

console.log(obj.Manager)
console.log(obj.Developer)
```